How to select the next lowest value and next highest value from a specific record value that's been flagged?
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee_Salary]
(
     [EmployeeID] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
     [EffectiveDate] [date] NULL,
     [EndDate] [date] NULL,
     [Salary] [decimal](15, 3) NULL,
     [ContractFlag] [varchar](255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee_Salary] 
VALUES
       ('100','01/01/2022','12/31/2022','10000','Completed'),
       ('100','01/01/2023','12/31/2023','20000','Completed'),
       ('100','01/01/2024','12/31/2024','30000','Active'),
       ('100','01/01/2025','12/31/2025','40000','Pending'),
       ('200','01/01/2022','12/31/2022','25000','Completed'),
       ('200','01/01/2023','12/31/2023','35000','Completed'),
       ('200','01/01/2024','12/31/2024','40000','Active'),
       ('200','01/01/2025','12/31/2025','10000','Pending'),
       ('300','01/01/2022','12/31/2022','20000','Completed'),
       ('300','01/01/2023','12/31/2023','30000','Completed'),
       ('300','01/01/2024','12/31/2024','40000','Active'),
       ('300','01/01/2025','12/31/2025','50000','Pending'),
       ('400','01/01/2024','12/31/2024','60000','Active'),
       ('400','01/01/2025','12/31/2025','10000','Pending') 




EmployeeID
EffectiveDate
EndDate
Salary
ContractFlag




100
01/01/2022
12/31/2022
10,000
Completed


100
01/01/2023
12/31/2023
20,000
Completed


100
01/01/2024
12/31/2024
30,000
Active


100
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
40,000
Pending


200
01/01/2022
12/31/2022
25,000
Completed


200
01/01/2023
12/31/2023
35,000
Completed


200
01/01/2024
12/31/2024
35,000
Active


200
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
40,000
Pending


300
01/01/2022
12/31/2022
10,000
Completed


300
01/01/2023
12/31/2023
20,000
Completed


300
01/01/2024
12/31/2024
30,000
Active


300
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
40,000
Pending


400
01/02/2024
12/31/2024
50,000
Active


400
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
60,000
Pending



I need to return:
Next lower value(cannot be equal to current active)



EmployeeID
EffectiveDate
EndDate
Salary
ContractFlag




100
01/01/2023
12/31/2023
20,000
Completed


200
01/01/2023
12/31/2023
25,000
Completed


300
01/01/2023
12/31/2023
20,000
Completed


400
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL



Next higher value(cannot be equal current active)



EmployeeID
EffectiveDate
EndDate
Salary
ContractFlag




100
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
20,000
Pending


200
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
25,000
Pending


300
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
20,000
Pending


400
01/01/2025
12/31/2025
60,000
Pending



I will insert into another table which should look like this:



EmployeeID
PrevIncreaseDate
NextIncreaseDate
PrevSalary
NextSalary
CurrentSalary




100
01/01/2023
01/01/2025
10,000
40,000
30,000


200
01/01/2022
01/01/2025
25,000
40,000
35,000


300
01/01/2023
01/01/2025
30,000
40,000
30,000


400
NULL
01/01/2025
NULL
60,000
50,000



I've tried using the LAG function, but this isn't effective if there are repeat salary amounts like example for EmployeeID 200. EmployeeID 200 has a current 'Active' Salary of 35,000 with a previous year 'Completed' Salary of also 35,000. The next lowest value is 25,000.
I also tried creating a sub-set of records and selecting the MAX or MIN record
SELECT 
    MAX(Salary), i.EmployeeID, i.EffectiveDate 
FROM 
    [Table] i
WHERE 
    i.Salary < (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM [Table] f 
                WHERE f.ContractFlag = 'Active')
GROUP BY 
    i.EmployeeID, i.EffectiveDate`

Also note that EmployeeID = 400 does not have a previous salary as they started in 2024.
There may be some cases where an employee does not having a pending contract for next year, and thus, should return null values.

Thank you! Sorry, I'm new to this. I've updated with sample above.

Your sample data doesn't include the specific requirement you mention, i.e. not so show the row if there is no change in value. You need to ensure sample data covers all edge cases.

In your expected results you have EmployeeId:200, PrevIncreaseDate:01/01/2022; where did that come from (the earliest row for EID:200 is 01/01/2022; why is that called 'increase')?

Having you scripted data different to your sample data is not helping. I assume its not possible for a salary to decrease? And I assume that 400 is getting a raise to 100,000 not a decrease to 10,000?

Here is a solution which meets the needs as stated. The first CTE removes rows where the salary doesn't change. Then its a straight-forward lead and lag as you already know how to do.
with cte1 as (
  select *
    , max(case when ContractFlag = 'Active' then Salary end) over (partition by EmployeeId) ActiveSalary
  from [dbo].[Employee_Salary]
), cte2 as (
  select *
    , lag(EffectiveDate) over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate asc) PreviousIncreaseDate
    , lag(Salary) over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate asc) PrevSalary
    , lead(EffectiveDate) over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate asc) NextIncreaseDate
    , lead(Salary) over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate asc) NextSalary
  from cte1
  where ContractFlag = 'Active' or ActiveSalary <> Salary
)
select EmployeeId, PreviousIncreaseDate, NextIncreaseDate, PrevSalary, NextSalary, Salary CurrentSalary
from cte2
where ContractFlag = 'Active'
order by EmployeeId, EffectiveDate asc;

DBFiddle

Yes! It worked! Thank you very much Dale K!
